# HOw to pass values dynamically using xpath automatically in a robot framework

Tags: robotframework

**How to pass values dynamically and randomly in a robot framework**
'If the code is like this

> li class="iysTreeLi parent_li" collapse="close" appended="false" 
>   data-desc="null" data-is_madatory="0" data-is_searchable="0"
>   data-is_child="1" data-parent_id="0" data-value="Sales & Marketing"
>   data-id="18865" data-type="functionals"> div class="iysTreeDiv">    Sales & Marketing
>   /a> /div> div class="clearfix"/> /li> li class="iysTreeLi parent_li"
>   collapse="close" appended="false" data-desc="null"
>   data-is_madatory="0" data-is_searchable="0" data-is_child="1"
>   data-parent_id="0" data-value="Banking, Financial Services, Insurance"
>   data-id="53599" data-type="functionals">

I m able to pass static values by an Id using xpath ..How to pass dynamic values using xpath and select the tree structure.

Comment: Pass values where, exactly? Are you calling a keyword? What keyword? What part of the xpath is dynamic? Have you tried simply using a variable within part of the xpath?

Comment: i am able to give like this .//*[@data-id='18865 and @data-type='functionals']   I can be able to locate the element.

Comment: I want that id to be generated randomly. so that it can dynamically select the element

Answer (score 5):

You can use variables inside xpath, just like you can with anything else:

```
| | Element should be visible | .//*[@data-id='${dataid}' and @data-type='functionals']
```

If your actual question is also about how to generate a random number, you can use Evaluate to run a small python function. For example, the following will return a random five-digit number:

```
| | ${random}= | Evaluate | random.randint(10000, 99999) | random
```

Comment: ya  how  to generate dataid value randomly.. and pass value into it.Its values is like this range '18865   ' I Want to generate like this .Its is for single digit.I want this range     '18865'                                               ${getfile}= Get File ${filename} 
${splitline}= Split To Lines ${getfile} 
${randomgen}= Generate Random String 1 [NUMBERS]
Return From Keyword ${splitline[${randomgen}]}

Comment: @KarthikaItsYourSkills: Are you asking how to compute a random number?

Comment: s five digit random number. I m able to generate for  single digit r double digit..

Comment: @KarthikaItsYourSkills: I've updated my answer to show how to generate a random five digit string.

Comment: Looking for the first type, Like to use `dynamic xpath` to locate element. +1. Thank you Bryan. It is useful way, let me try it out.